# How should I construct a database to store a lot of SHA1 data

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble constructing a database to store a lot of SHA1 data and efficiently return results.

I will admit SQL is not my strongest skill but as an exercise I am trying to use the data from https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords which returns results pretty quickly

This is my data:

```
mysql> describe pwnd;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pwndpass | binary(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select id, hex(pwndpass) from pwnd order by id desc limit 10;
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
| id        | hex(pwndpass)                            |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
| 306259512 | FFFFFFFEE791CBAC0F6305CAF0CEE06BBE131160 |
| 306259511 | FFFFFFF8A0382AA9C8D9536EFBA77F261815334D |
| 306259510 | FFFFFFF1A63ACC70BEA924C5DBABEE4B9B18C82D |
| 306259509 | FFFFFFE3C3C05FCB0B211FD0C23404F75E397E8F |
| 306259508 | FFFFFFD691D669D3364161E05538A6E81E80B7A3 |
| 306259507 | FFFFFFCC6BD39537AB7398B59CEC917C66A496EB |
| 306259506 | FFFFFFBFAD0B653BDAC698485C6D105F3C3682B2 |
| 306259505 | FFFFFFBBFC923A29A3B4931B63684CAAE48EAC4F |
| 306259504 | FFFFFFB58E389A0FB9A27D153798956187B1B786 |
| 306259503 | FFFFFFB54953F45EA030FF13619B930C96A9C0E3 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My question relates to quickly finding entries as it currently takes over 6 minutes

```
mysql> select hex(pwndpass) from pwnd where hex(pwndpass) = '0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38';
+------------------------------------------+
| hex(pwndpass)                            |
+------------------------------------------+
| 0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (6 min 31.82 sec)
```

Do I have the correct data types? I search for storing sha1 data and a Binary(20) field is advised but not sure how to optimising it for searching the data.

My MySQL install is a clean turnkey VM https://www.turnkeylinux.org/mysql I have not adjusted any settings other than giving the VM more disk space

Comment: How about creating an index?

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Quick google and I have something to read. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most obvious tips are:

- Create an index on the column.
- Don't convert every single row to hexadecimal on every search:

  ```
  select hex(pwndpass)
  from pwnd
  where hex(pwndpass) = '0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38';
  --    ^^^ This is forcing MySQL to convert every hash stored from binary to hexadecimal
  --        so it can determine whether there's a match
  ```

In fact, you don't even need hexadecimal at all, save for display purposes:

```
select id, hex(pwndpass) -- This is fine, will just convert matching rows
from pwnd
where pwndpass = ?
```

... where `?` is a placeholder that, in your client language, corresponds to a binary string.

If you need to run the query right in command-line, you can also use an [hexadecimal literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html):

```
select id, hex(pwndpass) -- This is fine, will just convert matching rows
from pwnd
where pwndpass = 0x0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38
```

Comment: Could you expand on how I should be doing the SELECT statement?  I have played around with it for days and struggled to get results

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation, your solution worked perfectly